# F# compiler error FS0030, problems with the Value Restriction

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement, value-restriction

I've read the blurb at [StrangeLights](http://www.strangelights.com/fsharp/wiki/default.aspx/FSharpWiki/ValueRestriction.html), I've read the [passage](http://books.google.com/books?id=NcrMkjVxahMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=FS0030+f%23) from Expert F# (page 119), but I can't see how they apply to my code:

For my tests, I want to check equality between floats, with a bit of tolerance. I'm converting everything to units of measure, but I want to be able to be 'generic':

```
let toleq (e:float<_>) a b = (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
```

I can then use this to check equality on different 'types' of float, or curry it to make a custom one:

```
toleqm = toleq 1.0e-10<m>
```

But I get the following message:

```
Type inference has inferred the signature
    val toleq : float<'u> -> float<'u> -> float<'u> -> bool
Either define 'toleq' as a simple data term, make it a function, or add a 
    type constraint to instantiate the type parameters.
```

I don't see how I can do any more to make it a function - I can't see any implicit parameters.

What's up?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error message on 1.9.6.2, can you show the whole tiny program that generates it?

Comment: There is no tiny program, just tried in FSI, that single line gives me the error.

Comment: Cross ref to another question on same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131456/understanding-f-value-restriction-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I messed around a bit and found the solution, in desperation, but I'm not sure that I understand why...

```
let toleq (e:float<_>) (a:float<_>) (b:float<_>) = (abs ( a - b ) ) < e
```

Ugh, it's almost as ugly as generic declarations in C#.