# F# Units of measure, problems with genericity 2

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460766/f-units-of-measure-problems-with-genericity) question, I still seem to be battling at the frontiers of what is possible, though I don't think that I'm doing anything particularly bleeding edge:

```
type Vector2d = { X: float<'u>; Y: float<'u> }
```

Gives me *error FS0039: The unit-of-measure parameter 'u' is not defined.*

And

```
type Vector2d = { X: float<_>; Y: float<_> }
```

Gives me *error FS0191: anonymous unit-of-measure variables are not permitted in this declaration.*

Is it the case that functions can handle 'generic' units of measure, but types can't?

Comment: Perspective: Using units _at all_ is 'bleeding edge'.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Vector2d<[<Measure>]'u> = { X: float<'u>; Y: float<'u> }
```

should do the trick

Note: This is correct as of the 1.9.6.2 CTP release but this api is not currently viewed as stable

Comment: f# really screws the syntax highlighting doesn't it :)

Comment: Any chance of looking at my question 1? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460766/f-units-of-measure-problems-with-genericity

Comment: @Benjol: is the answer from Brian not correct? It seems ok based on a quick once over

Comment: My answer might not be correct; apparently generic non-zero values were an unintentional feature of CTP.  There may be revisions with units in the next release (as well as a bunch of bug fixes to offer better diagnostics).

Comment: Yeah - the non core stuff should be viewed as a moving target- I should probably add a note to that effect on any post incase it becomes horribly out of date

Comment: @ShaggyCoUk, I just had a vague hope you might be able to solve the problem with the # on my seq - no disrespect to Brian...

Comment: I'm away from my f# environment (and will be for a week), I'll give it a try when I get back. Are you running the latest CTP release?