# Reusing units of measure across different types

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

*([Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460766/f-units-of-measure-problems-with-genericity), [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490780/f-units-of-measure-problems-with-genericity-2) [playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412459/how-to-generically-remove-f-units-of-measure) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419521/f-units-of-measure-lifting-values-to-floatsomething) [units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348853/units-of-measure-in-c-almost) of [measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398611/f-ununit-reunit-inside-a-function))*

I've just started using units of measure for something other than float for the first time.

After starting off complicated, I discovered that you can re-use units of measure across multiple 'types'.

```
[<Measure>] type mm

let a = 1<mm>
let b = 1.<mm>
```

Now I'm sitting here wondering how to update my existing mm type to reflect this possibility:

```
[<Measure>]
type mm =
    static member perMetre = 1000.0<mm/m>
    static member fromMetre (v:float<m>) = v * mm.perMetre
    static member toMetre (v:float<mm>) = v / mm.perMetre
    static member lift (v:float) = v * 1.0<mm>
```

**The question:** How do I write a function that can convert from `mm` to `m` (say) that can handle `int<mm> -> int<m>` AND `float<mm> -> float<m>`?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Kurt, here's the new version:

```
[<Measure>]
type mm =
    static member private perMetreFloat = 1000.0<mm/m>
    static member private perMetreInt = 1000<mm/m>
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("float")>]
    static member fromMetre (v:float<m>) = v * mm.perMetreFloat
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("float")>]
    static member toMetre (v:float<mm>) = v / mm.perMetreFloat
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("float")>]
    static member lift (v:float) = v * 1.0<mm>
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("int")>]
    static member fromMetre (v:int<m>) = v * mm.perMetreInt
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("int")>]
    static member toMetre (v:int<mm>) = v / mm.perMetreInt
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("int")>]
    static member lift (v:int) = v * 1<mm>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply overloading works sometimes (if you have an argument):

```
[<Measure>]
type MM =
    static member perMetre = 1000.0<mm/m>
    static member fromMetre (v:float<m>) = v * MM.perMetre
    static member toMetre (v:float<mm>) = v / MM.perMetre
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("0")>]
    static member lift (v:float) = v * 1.0<mm>
    [<OverloadIDAttribute("1")>]
    static member lift (v:int) = v * 1<mm>
```

Comment: Lurvely, works a treat, I have included the result in the bottom of my question.